# libpcap (>1.0.0) and PF_RING efficiency

Tags: c++, linux, networking, libpcap

I'm using libpcap 1.4.0 in order to capture packets from/to a device (I'm using linux).
I'm suffering from packet loss, and after a research about it, I found PF_RING, and now i'm considering using it.

The problem is, I don't really understand why using PF_RING is more efficient than using libpcap's PF_PACKET, when libpcap's default packet capture method is "zero-copy" (since libpcap 1.0.0), as well as PF_RING's...

Can someone please explain me why, with libpcap 1.0.0 and later, using PF_RING would be still more efficient (if it is actually more efficient) than not using it ?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 4):

according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8897187/288875 there is still one copy from the kernel's socket buffer (sk_buff) to the memory you will read. `PF_RING` seems **not** to do this copy (as far as I remember does pfring [bypass](http://www.ntop.org/products/pf_ring/) the normal kernel mechanism of handling data received from the network card).

Comment: OK, I think a got it now.. So in `PF_PACKET` you have one copy from the kernel `KSBUFF` to libpcaps' buffer which is in both kernel-space and user-space while in `PF_RING` you skip even that copy?

Comment: @user2508653 at what data rate do you get packet loss with libpcap??